# Unable to load the URL in iOS WebView when the button is clicked for the first time

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, wkwebview

The mobile app is all about showing a SharePoint website in a WebView. I am trying to get the URL of a third party website on click of a button which is a part of the WebView. Based on this URL, I am trying to show an alert. On the first click of the button, the URL I am looking for, is not loading and hence the alert is not showing up. However, I am able to see the URL for the second click of the button and I'm able to see the alert as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: With a little more details, it would be easier to investigate. Maybe a part of code!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please post the relevant code